# Encontrar el valor máximo y mínimo en una colección mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hola a todos he tratado de realizar una consulta en mongo la cual tiene que traer como respuesta el registro máximo y mínimo que hay es esa colección, en la foto que está a continuación me gustaría tener solo los registros donde engineHour = 25248 y engineHour = 27598

he intentado con esta consulta pero me da error

```
db.getCollection('eventos').aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: "",
        maxHour: {$min: "$engineHour"},
        minHour: {$max: "$engineHour"}
    }
  }
])
```

Gracias por. la ayuda que pudieran brindarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder usar [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) y / [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) en una etapa de agrupación, debes especificar el campo por el cual vas a agrupar. Tal como parece que tienes los documentos, una etapa de agregación parece no ser la opción más adecuada. Una consulta `find` ordenada te daría el resultado que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/518941/encontrar-el-valor-m%c3%a1ximo-y-m%c3%adnimo-en-una-colecci%c3%b3n-mongodb#comment923444_518941), para poder usar los operadores [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) y [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) en una etapa [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), debes especificar el campo por el cual estás haciendo la agrupación. En tu código dicho campo lo dejas como un `string` vacío.

Por otro lado, el uso de `$max` y `$min` que haces no es el correcto, ya que los valores que quieres comparar deberían estar en una lista.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una forma de hacer lo que quieres es usar un [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#std-label-read-operations-cursors), mediante el método [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-crud-read-cursor). La idea es realizar el ordenamiento sobre el cursor y luego obtener los documentos que tengan el valor máximo y mínimo para el campo especificado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const events = db.getCollection('eventos').find({}).sort({engineHour: 1}).toArray();
const max = events[events.length - 1];
const min = events[0];
```

En el código anterior, he aplicado el método [`sort()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#mongodb-method-cursor.sort) sobre el cursor para ordenar de [forma ascendente](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#std-label-sort-asc-desc), usando como parámetro el campo `engineHours`. Luego he aplicado el método [`toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#mongodb-method-cursor.toArray) para obtener en un `Array` todos los documentos del cursor ya ordenados. El resultado se lo he asignado a la variable `events`. Una vez tenemos los documentos ordenados en nuestro `Array`, es fácil obtener el máximo que será el último elemento del `Array` y el mínimo que será el primer elemento del `Array`.

Otra forma de hacerlo, usando un proceso de agregación, es básicamente lo mismo pero escrito en forma de etapas de agregación. Sin embargo, debes tomar en cuenta que utilizar una etapa [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) tiene sus particularidades, empezando por la [consistencia](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-consistency) del ordenamiento y [restricciones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#-sort-and-memory-restrictions) de memoria.

Para lograr el resultado, primero ordenaremos los documentos de forma ascendente, luego agruparemos todos los documentos en un `Array` y por último tomaremos el primer y el último elemento de dicho `Array`. Tal como hemos hecho con el cursor.

Por ejemplo:

```js
db.getCollection('eventos').aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "engineHour": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "docs": {
        "$push": "$$CURRENT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "max": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$docs",
          -1
        ]
      },
      "min": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$docs",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Esto nos devuelve 1 documento con 2 campos: `max` y `min`, donde `max` contiene el documento cuyo campo `engineHours` es el máximo valor en la colección y `min` contiene el documento opuesto.

Como puedes observar he agrupado por un campo `_id` establecido a `null`, y he creado un campo llamado `docs` donde he añadido todos los documentos de la colección ordenados en la etapa previa. Para ello he usado la variable del sistema [`$$CURRENT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) que devuelve el documento que se está procesando. Por último, en la etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), selecciono el primer y último elemento del `Array` de documentos, usando el operador [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), quedando así sólo aquél cuyo campo `engineHours` es el máximo de la colección y el que tiene el valor mínimo.

Puedes ver el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O2imHyZw3FL) con el resultado de aplicar esta operación de agregación a una colección.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.